# Counting columns in multiple files in r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a large dataset (~250,000 records) and I used `splitting` to make the data more approachable. I ended up with 250 splits.

I want to know which split has the most columns. I know I should be using `list.files`, but I am not sure how to make it work.

I created the following reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("a"),B = (c("b")), C = (c("c")))
df2 <- data.frame(A = c("a"),B = (c("b")))
df3 <- data.frame(A = c("a"))

write.csv(df1, file = "df1.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(df2, file = "df2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(df3, file = "df3.csv", row.names=FALSE)

filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
```

Looking at the example above, I'd like to know that `df1` has the most attributes compare to the other files.

Does `for` loop and a simple `ncol` function can make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.csv` is very slow compared to `readLines` if you only wnat to know the number of columns :

```
sapply(filenames, function(x) {y=readLines(x, n=1);nchar(y)-nchar(gsub(',','',y))+1})
#./df1.csv ./df2.csv ./df3.csv 
#        3         2         1
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you.
Is there a way for the output to be sorted by any chance?

Comment: maybe by using ... `sort(sapply(...))`?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason I get '1' for each file, but each file I know has 12 or 13 columns. Any ideas what's going on? I'm reading in files from the working directory using this code:
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
And then using your code: sapply(filenames, function(x) {y=readLines(x, n=1);nchar(y)-nchar(gsub(',','',y))+1})

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import each file to R u can use a `file.info()` function to obtain the size of each file

```
sapply(list.files(), file.info)
```

In another case u can use `read.csv(..., nrows = 10)` for example to see the structure and don't have to load the entire table

```
sapply(list.files(), function(...) ncol(read.csv(..., nrows = 10)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing off of @Andriy T.'s response, here is code that will produce a list of columns in each of your files:

```
lapply(list.files(),function(x){ncol(read.csv(x))})
```

From there, you can select the maximum, get the index, and figure out which file it corresponds to.